# Getting a 502 Bad Gateway on my angular decoupled project even though the server status shows as online

Tags: angular, pm2

I have a decoupled site with Drupal 8 backend and an Angular 6 frontend. Everything was working fine but now I am getting a 502 Bad Gateway which sometimes seems to work but as soon as I refresh it gives the 502 Bad Gateway again.

- restarted the pm2 server successfully
- Changed the port in the server.ts file to 8000 and also in the nginx config file but nothing changed
- Confirmed that the code is working by pulling the latest code on local and point to the dev database
- Not seeing any weird traffic or even spikes in bandwidth on the server
- Checked the disk usage and there is enough space on the server (edited)

This is the error showing on pm2 monit
`Error: listen EADDRINUSE 0.0.0.0:4000` (edited)

Answer (score 0):

This error clearly shows that the port `4000`is already in use. Try to run the application in another port.

Comment: Thanks for the response Jibin but if you can check in the things I have already done you can see I have already tried to change the port to something different

Comment: Well changing port didn't work.Can't say more without checking the whole exception stack. Btw have you tried to change the port via CL arguments like `ng serve --port 3000`

Answer (score 0):

I have same issues with Angular projects.

In order to fix this I found a solution is to have this npm script when working in GitHub Codespaces:

```json
"dev": "ng serve --port 3001 --host=0.0.0.0 --disable-host-check"
```

I needed to have both: `--host=0.0.0.0` and `--disable-host-check`, running them separately wasn't solving the issue. Sometimes I had to change the `--port` setting, maybe due to caching or something.

Also, I think when using Gitpod there is no need in having these workarounds.